# Adding dynamic content using jQuery .replaceWIth

Tags: jquery, dynamic-content

I have following code on my HTML page.

```
<div id="dynBtn">
<span>Some content</span>
</div>
```

I am making an AJAX call that returns the following HTML content (as string):

```
<button id="bNew">New</button>
```

I am able to successfully replace the above  by executing the following jQuery script from within the successful return of AJAX call:

```
...
//ajax call
...
        success: function(retVal)
        {
            $("div#dynBtn").replaceWith(retVal);
        } 
...
```

I am able to see the 'New' button added on the page.
But when I click on it, it does not trigger the corresponding jQuery

```
$("#bNew).click()function(){
    //does not come here.
});
```

The js file containing this code is definitely loaded - I have confirmed this much.

Any suggestions on how can I make this new button trigger the script after it is dynamically added as above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Wrap the dynamic element inside a `<div>` that is static, and listen for the `click()` event on the outer element. @CBroe has linked a very useful explanation.